# How to download pdf file on next.js/React.js typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, file, next.js

This is my component to download pdf file.
I have pdf file named `resumeroshan.pdf` inside Assets folder

```
"use client";
import resume from "../../Assets/resumeroshan.pdf";
export default function About() {
  return(
   <div>
    <a href={resume} download="roshan">
      <div className="mt-[25px] flex w-[150px] cursor-pointer justify-center rounded bg-[#007aff] px-5 py-3 align-middle text-white hover:border-[1px] hover:border-[#007aff] hover:bg-white hover:text-[#007aff]">
        Download CV
      </div>
    </a>
   </div>
  );
}
```

When I clicked Download CV button nothing is happening, there is no error even in the console.

I have also added `declare module '*.pdf'`  inside `global.d.ts` by following some instruction from some sources but it didn't helped either.

Can you please help me with how to download the file on button click in next.js/React.js. Above code is from next.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For NextJs 13, put your pdf file in public directory (lets say `rohsan-resume.pdf`) and then use it like this

```
<a href="rohsan-resume.pdf" download>
      <div className="mt-[25px] flex w-[150px] cursor-pointer justify-center rounded bg-[#007aff] px-5 py-3 align-middle text-white hover:border-[1px] hover:border-[#007aff] hover:bg-white hover:text-[#007aff]">
        Download CV
      </div>
    </a>
```

Link to the vercel discussion [link to pdf](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/25981)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to import and download `.pdf` files in a way you are trying to do.

You should put the files you want to download in `public` folder. Then use following

```
<a href="/resume.pdf" download="roshan.pdf">
  <div className="mt-[25px] flex w-[150px] cursor-pointer justify-center rounded bg-[#007aff] px-5 py-3 align-middle text-white hover:border-[1px] hover:border-[#007aff] hover:bg-white hover:text-[#007aff]">
    Download CV
  </div>
</a>
```